# DOJO: Error 416 in response header when using DataGrid with JsonRest

Tags: json, datagrid, dojo

I am trying the tutorial examples to populate the datagrid using the Json data through the JsonRest store, but I get an empty grid and in the response header it is 416 "Requested range not satisfied" I am using Jboss server for the request. Please let me know if any configurations are missed out. I am able to get the value of Json displayed using xhr.get, but want to link the datagrid directly to the JsonRestStore for direct crud operations. Please help.

Thanks
Ann

Code below:

```
<script >
require([
         "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
         "dojo/store/Memory",
         "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
         "dojo/_base/xhr",
        "dojo/store/JsonRest",
         "dojo/domReady!",
        "dojo/request"
     ], function(DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore, xhr,JsonRestStore){
         var grid,  dataStore;

         var myStore = new dojo.store.JsonRest({target:"MyData/myDatanew.json"});
        var grid1;
       grid1 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
             store: dataStore = dojo.data.ObjectStore({objectStore: myStore}),

             structure: [
                        {name: "Name", field: "name", width: "84px" },
                        {name: "Abbreviation", field: "abbreviation", width: "84px" }
             ]
         }, "new"); // blank grid comes up

         grid1.startup();

</script>
```